# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' for Google Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, libraries, pako

I have been using this same code in Google Apps Scripts for quite some time and I have started receiving the following error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

This just started happening this week after many months of running the script. I can still push the script through in Google by pressing run multiple times, but this is not scalable.

Here is the code and the error is attached the line of code that says `eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://cdn.rawgit.com/nodeca/pako/master/dist/pako.js').getContentText());`:

```
function mavenlink_raw(s1, options, report_id) {
  

      // PULL MAVENLINK REPORT
      var url = "https://api.mavenlink.com/api/v1/scheduled_jobs/insights_report_exports/"+report_id
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
      var dataSet = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
      var gzip = dataSet.latest_success.url
    
      // CONVERT GZIP TO CSV
      eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://cdn.rawgit.com/nodeca/pako/master/dist/pako.js').getContentText());
      var charData = UrlFetchApp.fetch(gzip).getContent();
      var binData = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < charData.length; i++) {
        binData.push(charData[i] < 0 ? charData[i] + 256 : charData[i]);
      }
      var data = pako.inflate(binData);
      var decoded = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        decoded += String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
      }
      var rows = Utilities.parseCsv(decoded);
```

Comment: Checked `pako.js` and see if they updated anything?

Answer (score 1):

Try [Utilities.unzip()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#unzipblob) or [Utilities.ungzip()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#ungzipblob) instead of the `pako` library.